# Adding a Image into a MySQL Database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way in adding a image into a MySQL database?

Comment: Add the image path and name, that works for me

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do that? I think that for most applications you will be better off storing the image in a folder on your webserver and adding the location/details of the image to the database.

Answer (score 5):

Not to add it.  Store the images in a folder on your server, and add the path to the file instead.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Why? it answers the question

Comment: Files are stored on file systems. Data is stored in databases.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the data of the image is a bad idea. It's bulky, and once you retrieve the data, you then have to re-encode it to produce the image. The easiest way is to store the image on your server, and just store the location in the database. Then you can use your rows to point to the image.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is apparently **not** to add image into a MySQL database
There are only few cases when such unnatural thing can be used,  and in the field of the web-development there are none.

Comment: In which cases is this acceptable? Nothing comes in my mind.

Comment: @PLB http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers said not to store the image.  If you choose to do so anyway, check out BLOBs which were meant for large blocks of data.